# "The identity of this website has not been verified."

Tags: internet, google-chrome

I'm using chrome on Ubuntu 12.10. There are always message from chrome :

```
`The identity of this website has not been verified.

Your connection to askubuntu.com is not encrypted.`
```

Facebook and Twitter do not appear such message. What's wrong? What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, if you click the "What do these mean?" you will see 
https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617&p=ui_security_indicator

> The site isn't using SSL. This icon displays for http:// sites. Most
>   sites don’t need to use SSL because they don’t handle sensitive
>   information. Avoid entering sensitive information, such as your credit
>   card information or bank login information, on the page. If sensitive
>   information is being requested on a site not using SSL, consider
>   contacting the website owner.